# Kotlin binary if condition

Tags: kotlin

I have so confusing about this program.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val condition1 = true
    val condition2 = false
    val condition3 = true

    val state = (if (condition1) 1 else 0) shl 2 or
            (if (condition2) 1 else 0) shl 1 or
            (if (condition3) 1 else 0)

    println(state)

    when (state) {
        0b100 -> println("Only condition1 is true.")
        0b010 -> println("Only condition2 is true.")
        0b001 -> println("Only condition3 is true.")
        0b101 -> println("condition1 and condition3 are true.")
        0b110 -> println("condition1 and condition2 are true.")
        0b011 -> println("condition2 and condition3 are true.")
        0b111 -> println("All conditions are true.")
        else -> println("All conditions are false.")
    }
}
```

I expected printing "condition1 and condition3 are true." . but this code always return else block "All conditions are false."

Additionally, My IDE warn 'never reachable' like below.

[image]

Why is this happend ? Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot some parentheses. The result of the first line of your expression is getting or'ed with `(if (condition2) 1 else 0)` and then that entire result is getting shifted left by 1. So now the very first 1 has been shifted left by 3.

Add parentheses to the second line to fix it:

```
val state = (if (condition1) 1 else 0) shl 2 or
        ((if (condition2) 1 else 0) shl 1) or
        (if (condition3) 1 else 0)
```

And actually, only one of the branches can be reachable since you are working with local constant inputs and local calculations only. The compiler is only warning you about the ones it is sophisticated enough to detect.